# C++ new line in file not working

Tags: c++

Yesterday I post about a big contract for a new account program that must be in C++. My question closed but I think
because it had to many errors. With much work and consuling from local C++ expert I've fixed the original codes we had:

```
#include <accounting.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *main()
{
    accounting bank = 100debits;
    bank = bank + 200debits;
    return printf("bal: %accounting\n", bank);
}
```

And new version with some classes we defined works well but the only problem is C++ can't write a new line to file.
The codes below work as is but I get no output to file if I put back the comment line.

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
#define accounting float
#define print_accounting(x)  x "%0.2f"
#define debits * 1.0F
#define credits * -1.0F

int main()
{
    accounting bank = 100 debits;
    bank = bank + 200 debits;
    char my_bal[((unsigned short)-1)];
    sprintf(my_bal, print_accounting("bal:"), bank);
    char write_file[((unsigned short)-1)];
    write_file[NULL] = 0;
    strcat(write_file, "@echo ");
    strcat(write_file, my_bal);
//  strcat(write_file, "\n");  -- Wont work --
    strcat(write_file, " > c:\\SAP_replace\\bal.txt");
    system(write_file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using (especialy unsafe) C-functions when you want to use C++?

Comment: thats some giant arrays ...

Comment: You would better use fstreams (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/) in C++

Comment: +1 for bringing a smile to my face. Good luck to the guy who specified that you must write in C++. By the way, you might want to start with "Hello world" and work from there.

Comment: @KarthikT 64 kilobytes, and that should be enough for everyone…

Comment: @Potatoswatter 128kb actually (2X 64kb) and in just 1 10-liner main function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`echo` will automatically write a newline to the end of the file.

If you want *two* newlines, just add another line similar to:

```
system ("echo. >>c:\SAP_replace\\bal.txt");
```

after the current `system()` call.

Or you could throw away the entire archaic idea of spawning another process to do output, and instead use `iostreams` to do the job. That's the way you *should* be doing it in C++, something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main (void) {
    float fval = 0.123f;
    std::ofstream os ("bal.txt");
    os << "bal: " << fval << '\n';
    os.close();
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
bal: 0.123
```

Comment: Note that `float` is no good for accounting, since it loses the precision of one cent when the magnitude is greater than about $80,000.

Comment: Absolutely correct, @Potatoswatter, `double` really isn't much better in that, though the precision is much greater, errors can still accumulate. I'd tend to work with integers or longs and treat everything as cents, converting to dollars/cents (substitute your favorite currency here) on input/output to user. That will probably be more accurate _and_ faster, and should work just about everywhere except Zimbabwe (I actually have a 100 trillion dollar Zim banknote in my collection).

Comment: @paxdiablo The maxim "don't store currency as floats" is good advice. However, there is no loss of precision if the currency is stored as cents, and there is no currency conversion. The operators that result in loss of precision don't appear in many common cases. But, of course, "don't store currency as floats" is safest.